# C#: Loop or Array

Tags: c#

i have this code for c#

```
var wordCounts1 = myInterface.GetWordCounts(new[] {
"one", "one", "two", "three", "three",});
```

the expected output should be:

```
{"one", 2}, {"two", 1}, {"three",2}
```

what should I use to get this output loop or array?

Comment: You already have an array. Use loop!

Comment: try `GroupBy` and `Count`

Comment: If you need to find the count of your repeating values in array use LINQ

Comment: Please read [ask]. Neither "loop" nor "array" are an appropriate answer to the question "what should I use to get this output". How do you compute the output by now?

Comment: `"loop or array"` - Those are two entirely different and not-mutually-exclusive things.  So the question you're asking doesn't really make sense.  Have you *tried anything* to get the desired output?  What didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Grouping by word should work

```
new[] { "one", "one", "two", "three", "three" }
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .Select(x => new
        {
            Word = x.Key,
            Count = x.Count()
        });
```